# Parsing the xml using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Parsing the following xml.

http://www.livehindustan.com/home/rssfeed/1.html

i tried with simplepie, but it returns error. Any other custom way to extract the guid, pubDate, bigimage of the items in the xml feed using PHP

Comment: tried [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)? check this [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Tried but the xml which i am using does not have separate tags for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$xmlstr = file_get_contents("http://www.livehindustan.com/home/rssfeed/1.html");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(trim($xmlstr));
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
   echo 'guid =>', $item->guid, PHP_EOL, 
    ' pubDate => ', $item->pubDate, PHP_EOL,
    ' bigimage => ', $item->bigimage, PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note: I have used `trim($xmlstr)` because your feed contains a blank line at the beginning, which is not valid for XML.